# Class that extends Array and properly overrides 'map' method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to implement a class that extends Array and properly overrides 'map' method. the items in the array must extend a certain type.

implementation without a constrain on the items is working as expected:

```js
export class MyClass<T> extends Array<T> {
  constructor(...items: T[]) {
    super(...items);

    // Set the prototype explicitly. (typescript does not allow to extend base classes like Array)
    // see: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, VectorArr.prototype);
  }

  map<K>(callback: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => K, thisArg?: any): MyClass<K> {
    const mapped = super.map(callback, thisArg);
    return new MyClass(...mapped);
  }
}
```

now lets say each item in the array must be extend `Vector` type:

```
interface MyVector {}

export class MyClass<T extends MyVector> extends Array<T> {
  constructor(...items: T[]) {
    super(...items);

    // Set the prototype explicitly. (typescript does not allow to extend base classes like Array)
    // see: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, VectorArr.prototype);
  }

// TS2416: Property 'map' in type 'MyClass<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'T[]'.   Types of parameters 'callback' and 'callbackfn' are incompatible.     Type 'U' is not assignable to type 'MyVector'.  lib.es5.d.ts(1441, 9): This type parameter might need an `extends MyVector` constraint.
// v
  map<K extends MyVector>(callback: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => K, thisArg?: any): MyClass<K> {
    const mapped = super.map(callback, thisArg);
    return new MyClass(...mapped);
  }
}
```

now we got an error: basically, typescript says that because the base class(the native Array) implementation does not have to extend `MyVector`(Da!) my implementation is wrong(not compatible with the base class method - generic type `K` from my implementation is extending `MyVector` but generic type `U` from the native implementation does not have this constrain).

well, seriously? I try to enforce a more specific type than the native array, why does typescript suggest me to extend the base class method implementation so it will extend MyVector as well?

how do I make typescript stop yelling it me?

Comment: Java !== JavaScript

Comment: java was not tagged, but looking it the edit history it seems that it was mistakenly added by Federico who edited my question

Comment: @EliavLouski: you are misreading the history. The original question had [tag:java] and Frederico removed it.

Comment: Exactly the opposite - it was *removed*. Notice how it is red and stricken out. Also look at revision #1 which lists it.

Comment: well, sorry about it ;)