# Extending base class method with the same name and unrelated type

Tags: typescript

a very simple requirement yet I could not find a solution. I implement a `class B` which inherits `class A` and overrides a method of `class A` but with a different type. the method names *must* be the same.

```
class A {
  method(): string {
    return "1";
  }
}

class B extends A {
// TS2416: Property 'method' in type 'B' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A'.   Type '() => number' is not assignable to type '() => string'.     Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
// v
  method(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729485/override-method-with-different-argument-types-in-extended-class-typescript) (from almost 5 years ago) explains that typescript inheritance implements subtyping so a method on a class that inherits from a class that has a method with the same name must be a subtype of the original method. however, I really need this option and I want to suppress these typescript errors in a reliable way.

is this possible in typescript(another way than 'ts-ignore' all over the place)?

Comment: I've put an answer, but this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You think you want to do this, but you really don't. I'm sure there is a better solution for you. Also the more I think about this is a duplicate of your linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729485/override-method-with-different-argument-types-in-extended-class-typescript. It lists all the reasons why you shouldn't do this.

Comment: You are right. this is exactly an XY situation. yet I'm quite sure that in my case a clear solution to Y will bring a direct solution to [X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326319/class-that-extends-array-and-properly-overrides-map-method)

Answer (score 0):

`B` *must* be assignable to `A` or your inheritance is invalid.

You're breaking one of the principles of inheritance here, which is that a sub class supports the interface of its super class.

You should always be able to use a child class is if it was its parent class. If you break that rule it's a type error.

So this a valid and legitimate type error, what you're trying to do is unsound.

---

In order to make `B` assignable to `A` then the return type of `A.method()` could be changed to return `string | number`.

```
class A {
  method(): string | number { // added "| number" here
    return "1";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  method(): number { // fine
    return 1;
  }
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oFsCmAXAFgewBMAKASgC5oIsAnASwDsBzaAH2noFc0AjDaxFKmjVsHavWgAiAIySA3IIC+SZUlCQYAIWgYAHlgz0CMeMlSZchUhU48+AocNHjo0hamWKgA)

Comment: this may be right in obvious situations like the one I gave here, but in others, it's not that simple to determine. but what if I don't have access to the base implementation? for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326319/class-that-extends-array-and-properly-overrides-map-method)